# What does "A is recognized over B" mean? Is it a correct expression?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence as following:

> Effort is recognized over talent.

Does that mean effort is more important than talent? Is this expression correct in standard English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, “recognized” means “rewarded” and “over” means “more (often) than”.

> **rec·og·nize**  [rek-*uhg*-nahyz]
>   ***<sup>verb (used with object), rec·og·nized, rec·og·niz·ing.</sup>*** 
> [. . .]
> **9.** to show appreciation of (achievement, service, merit, etc.), as by some reward, public honor, or the like.
> <sub>Source: [Dictionary.com definition of “recognize”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recognize)</sub>

A faithful rephrasing would be:

> Effort is more appreciated and rewarded than talent.

Basically, it's saying that it's more important to put forth effort over time (or possibly get better at something) than to rely on your natural abilities.